# Airport Bus Transfer from Madrid Airport to City Center

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, madrid, mad

Please advise if there is an airport bus transfer from Madrid Airport (Terminal 4 Seattleite) to the city center (if my hotel booking is at Courtyard Marriott).

Comment: Why don't you ask the hotel?  The'd know

Comment: Just one point: you may arrive at T4S but you'll use the little underground train to T4 where you'll emerge from the airport.

Comment: As far as I remember (I used this airport a couple of times a long time ago) there are no shuttle buses since the airport is served by subway. There are however regular buses that stop at the airport.
There is a free shuttle bus going through all the terminals.

Comment: I think I found something here https://www.esmadrid.com/en/airport-express?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 1):

This hotel [does not provide an airport shuttle](https://www.marriott.com/hotels/maps/travel/madcy-courtyard-madrid-princesa/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, and I suggest that the best bet is the Metro (there's a station in T4 near the main exit, well signposted). Line 8 to Nuevos Ministerios, change to line 6 for Argüelles.

Comment: Thanks for info. I found the airport bus here https://www.esmadrid.com/en/airport-express?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: I ought to delete my answer, But how close does it get you to the hotel, though?

Comment: 12 minutes of walk from the drop off point to the hotel, which is suitable to me